# Expectation values of functions

Tags: expected-value

This question is more to do with interpretation than calculation. I have a model which predicts the probability of a detector 'firing' under a certain intensity of signal, or actually in this case lack of a signal. The detector is made of a number of sub-pixels so the probability of none of the sub-pixels firing in a certain window is

$$
P(N=0) = \exp^{-\lambda(x, \gamma)}
$$

The detector is made of a number of elements so the probability of none of them firing is given by

$$
P(tot = 0) = \Pi P_{(pix)}(N=0) 
$$

There is some uncertainty on gamma which I assume to be distributed according to some PDF so the expectation value for the total probability is now
$$
\int (\Pi P_{(pix)}(\gamma)) P(\gamma)d\gamma
$$

My problem is this - I might, and often do, want to look at individual pixels. So I might want to move the integral inside the product. Or alternatively I might wish to calculate the expected mean value in the first equation.

$$
\bar \lambda = \int \lambda(x,\gamma)P(\gamma)d\gamma
$$

I know what happens numerically if I compare F[E(X)] and E[F(X)] but I struggling with the conceptual difference between the cases. What is the difference between the product of the expectation values for the individual pixels and the expectation value of the product.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that the $x's$ are also random, in which case what follows is to be understood "conditional on the $x$'s".

There are conceivably *four* "cases" here ($f_{\gamma}(\gamma)$ is the probability density function of $\gamma$),

$$ \begin{align} 
& \prod_{i=1}^{n}P_i\left(\lambda[x,E(\gamma)]\right) = \prod_{i=1}^{n}P_i\left[\lambda\left(x,\int\gamma f_{\gamma}(\gamma)\mathrm{d}\gamma\right)\right] &\qquad [1]\\ 
& \prod_{i=1}^{n}P_i(E[\lambda(x,\gamma)]) = \prod_{i=1}^{n}P_i\left[\int f_{\gamma}(\gamma)\lambda(x,\gamma)\mathrm{d}\gamma\right] &\qquad [2]\\
& \prod_{i=1}^{n}E\left(P_i[\lambda(x,\gamma)]\right)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\left(\int f_{\gamma}(\gamma)P_i[\lambda(x,\gamma)]\mathrm{d}\gamma\right) &\qquad [3] \\
& E\left[\prod_{i=1}^{n}P_i[\lambda(x,\gamma)]\right] = \int f_{\gamma}(\gamma)\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}P_i[\lambda(x,\gamma)]\right)\mathrm{d}\gamma &\qquad [4]
\end{align}$$

Since the above are conditional on the $x'$s, the expected value is taken with respect to $\gamma$ only.

Moving from $[1]$ to $[4]$, what we are doing is gradually *increasing the extent to which we are allowing the uncertainty in $\gamma$ to interact with the structure*.

In $[1]$, we "sweep away" this uncertainty by using, instead of $\gamma$, a centrality measure for it, $E(\gamma)$, and then calculate all consecutive interactions (trough the function $\lambda ()$, through the $P_i$'s, and then through $\prod$), using just this centrality measure.

In $[2]$, we allow the uncertainty in $\gamma$ to interact with the function $\lambda()$, by permitting $\lambda ()$ to take the various values it takes for each possible value of $\gamma$, and *then* averaging. But after that, the uncertainty stops affecting the expression, since it has been averaged out.

In $[3]$, we allow the uncertainty in $\gamma$ to interact directly with the composite function  $P_i\circ \lambda$: for each possible value of $\gamma$ we calculate the magnitude $P_i[x,\lambda(\gamma)]$, and then averaging over it.

In other words, each expression is affected by a different random quantity.

Depending on the actual functional forms employed, these three expressions in general give different results. Only if the *affine* property is preserved, they are equivalent:
If, say, $\lambda(x,\gamma) = a_1 + h(x)\gamma$ and $P_i = a_2+b_1\lambda$, then , conditional on the $x$'s, the three expressions will give identical results because of the linearity property of the expected value operator.

But if non-affine forms are involved the equality breaks. Why? Because with non-linearity, each possible value of $\gamma$ will affect differently "itself" and $\lambda$ ($[1]$ against $[2]$), and also it will affect differently $\lambda$ and $P_i \circ \lambda$ ($[2]$ against $[3]$). If, say, $\lambda(x,\gamma) = x+ \gamma^2$, $\lambda$ is essentially not a function of $\gamma$ but a function *of a non-linear function* of $\gamma$. In other words, non-linearity "implies" another function composition. In this example, if nevertheless $P_i$ is an affine function of $\lambda$, then while $[1]$ is not in general equal to $[2]$, still, $[2]$ is equal to $[3]$.

The same reasoning applies to $[4]$: in it, the uncertainty in $\gamma$ is allowed to interact withe the whole product, before averaging it out. You should not be confused with the case where "the $P_i$'s are independent". The question is "independent with respect to what?" Presumably, with respect to the $x's$. But they are not independent with respect to $\gamma$ -and here our issue is the uncertainty in $\gamma$.

If the $P_i$'s are independent with respect to the $x$'s (and you indicate that this indeed holds), then $[4]$ is the average (always with respect to $\gamma$) joint probability, while $[3]$ is the product of the average marginal probabilities. $[4]$ acknowledges fully the uncertainty in $\gamma$, while $[3]$ gives you the joint probability when the uncertainty in $\gamma$ has collapsed in its expected value.

Comment: Thank you a thorough answer. I think you have answered my question. It still seems odd to be that it can be the case that the product of the average marginal probabilities is not the same as the average joint probability - however it is clearly the case. I feel like if i measure the expected value for each sensor experimentally the product of those should be what I would find if I measured the probability for the entire detector. In fact I might do this it's tedious but I think I want to prove it to myself.

Comment: I suggest that you do it, it will help clear away the false impression. Assume the $x$'s are identical for each $i=1,..,n$. Then

$$\prod_{i=1}^{n}E\left(P_i[\lambda(x,\gamma)]\right) = \Big[E\big(\exp^{-\lambda(x, \gamma)}\big)\Big]^n$$

while

$$E\left[\prod_{i=1}^{n}P_i[\lambda(x,\gamma)]\right] = E\big(\exp^{-n\lambda(x, \gamma)}\big)$$

If you set $z \equiv \exp^{-\lambda(x, \gamma)}$ and $f(z) \equiv z^n$ then this is a classic case of Jensen's Inequality, $f(E[z])$ against $E[f(z)]$